# Logstash for Vagrant: Address already in use

Tags: vagrant, logstash, bind, vagrantfile, elastic-stack

I have a Vagrant image in which there is an application; it is reachable in the Vagrant image if you call the port `2401` and depending on the service that you want, you call a specific address (i.e. "`curl -X GET  http://127.0.0.1:2401/provider/ipfix`"). To retrieve the output outside the Vagrant machine I have set a port forwarding in the Vagrant file (`"config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 2401, host: 8080`"), thus using the command "`curl -X GET  http://127.0.0.1:8080/provider/ipfix`" from host I get the same output.

I am now on the phase of installing *Logstash*. My issue is that when I run *Logstash* with the config file I get the error "Address already in use". I tried to use also fields to guide to the specific output. Below is my *Logstash* config file. What workaround would you suggest?

```
input {
 tcp {
    host => localhost
    port => 8080
    add_field => {
     "field1" => "provider"
     "field2" => "ipfix"
        } 
    codec => netflow {
      versions => [10]
      target => ipfix
    }
    type => ipfix
  }
}

output {
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }

  elasticsearch {
    index => "IPFIX-logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you're expecting Logstash to use TCP to connect to localhost:8080 to fetch information that it will then process.

That's not what this input does. This creates a *listener* on 127.0.0.1:8080, so the error message about 'already in use' is quite correct.

Considering you're using curl as an example of fetching this data, I suggest [the `http_poller` plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.2/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html) is better for what you want.

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      IPFIX => "http://127.0.0.1:8080/provider/ipfix"
    }
    request_timeout => 30
    schedule => { "every" => "5s" }
    add_tags => [ 'ipfix' ]
  }
}
```

This will hit the known-working CURL URL every 5 seconds with a `GET` request.

Comment: You are right, that's what I want. Your proposal seems a legit solution. I cannot try it now, I will do at my earliest convenience and I will update. Many thanks!